# Recursive function looping through obj props not working

Tags: javascript

why does this only alert 1 ?

```
function test() {
 var myobj = {
  a : '1st level prop',
  b : 'findme',
  c : {
    aa : '2nd level prop',
    bb : 'findme',
    cc : {
     aaa : '3rd level prop',
     bbb : 'findme'
    }
   }
 }
 function countem(needle,haystack) {
  var count = count || 0;
  for(var i in haystack) {
   if (typeof(haystack[i]) == 'object') {
    countem(needle,haystack[i]); 
   } else {
    if (needle == haystack[i]) {
     count++; 
    }
   }
  }
  return count;
 }
 alert(countem('findme',myobj));
}
```

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with JavaScript, but isn't there a difference between an array and an object? It appears to me that the `typeof(haystack[i]) == 'object'` is returning false thus only counting the first one it found. Also, it should be adding the result of countem to your count because it started a new function...

Comment: @animuson : You are not familiar with JavaScript, this is how you can look at an objects properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add in the count on the recursive call.

```
function test() {
 var myobj = {
  a : '1st level prop',
  b : 'findme',
  c : {
    aa : '2nd level prop',
    bb : 'findme',
    cc : {
     aaa : '3rd level prop',
     bbb : 'findme'
    }
   }
 }
 function countem(needle,haystack) {
  var count = 0;
  for(var i in haystack) {
   if (typeof(haystack[i]) == 'object') {
    count = count + countem(needle,haystack[i]); 
   } else {
    if (needle == haystack[i]) {
     count++; 
    }
   }
  }
  return count;
 }
 alert(countem('findme',myobj));
}
```

Comment: or `count += countem(needle,haystack[i]);` for the byte-savers out there.

Comment: yep this was the solution, 
for some reason I had thought that count would sort've bubble up from the inner function but I think I understand why that wouldn't happen. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

because you reset `count` on every call to `countem`.

```
if (typeof(haystack[i]) == 'object') {
    count += countem(needle,haystack[i]);
}
```